# VMware version and window server 2012

Tags: windows, vmware, windows-server-2012

I would like to ask for an advice,
I am trying to install Window Server 2012 in my machine(running on Win 8.1 ). My main purpose for now is the user can access my network(report server)through other machine. 
Which of those **Window Server 2012 Standard** or **Essential or Hyper-V Server** or **Active Directory Federation** should be installed? 
And another thing is VMware should be installed before installing the servers and OSes, again which version of VMware do you suggest to be used?

Thanks

Comment: [VMware ] is the name of a firm, it is not the name of a product. It is also a deprecated tag here on [su].  Please decide first on what you want to use, a type-1 hypervisor (such as esxi) or a type-2 hypervisor (such as vmware-player, vmware-workstation or vmware fusion (the last for on OSX).  Consider if you want to run multiple VMs at the same time (vmware player vs workstation). Then use the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1105514/edit) link to add more detail.

Comment: I ended up using Window Server 2012(because microsoft download link is having problem that time) on Parallel.